# Re-initialize linked list to be empty

Tags: c++

I'm trying to write a function that initializes a linked list ti be empty using recursion. Here is its code but it is not working. The output I get after calling this function and trying to insert another item in the list, the program crashes.

```
void r_make_empty(struct Node *p){
Node *temp;
if(p == NULL){
return;
}
temp = p;
r_make_empty(p->next);
delete temp;
}
```

Comment: Impossible to answer without seeing insert. I'm guessing you've deleted the root node so have nothing to insert onto.

Comment: My crystal ball tells me your reusing whatever `p` points to (which is technically undefined, as it is left dangling) in the calling code you inconveniently did *not* post with this question. This code could be shorter, btw, and made to work as you probably wish if `p` were passed by reference-to-pointer rather than value-of-pointer.

Comment: There's nothing lethally wrong with the code you've shown, though it's a little bloated `void r_make_empty(Node* p){ if(p) r_make_empty(p->next); delete p; }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your below code is absolutely correct. It is very difficult to answer without looking at your full codes.

```
void r_make_empty(struct Node *p){
Node *temp;
if(p == NULL){
return;
}
temp = p;
r_make_empty(p->next);
delete temp;
```

}

But it is not clear how are you calling this method. Call this method like below:-

```
r_make_empty(head->next);
```

Once created a link list avoid delete the head node if you are creating the list in a function.